# How can I programatically determine if a program is in the user's PATH

Tags: c++

I have an application that for debugging purposes launches an editor with a log file. The editor was set to kedit. After a RedHat release update, we no longer had kedit. We simply changed the default editor and added an environment variable to let the user choose what editor they preferred.

The problem is that if the user sets the environment variable to an editor that does not exist or is not is their path, nothing happens. I will like to see if the editor exists, and if not notify them. Is there a way to do that in C++?

Comment: You can walk through the components of `$PATH` and check if the file `<the_component_of_PATH>/binary_name` exists.

Comment: If you're running on linux only, you can use `which`. It returns `0` when the binary is found or `1` if it isn't. (see `man 1 which`)

Comment: `system("which ${EDITOR}")`?

Comment: @CarlNorum Please don't suggest using `system()`. It's a hack.

Comment: Why? It's *extremely* convenient in this case.  If you do it yourself you're just going to end up reimplementing it anyway, for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Why not just ask the user to for the location of the editor using a file dialog?

Comment: @H2CO3 That was my first thought, but I was hoping for something a little more straight forward. I tried using `popen` which "worked" however, I don't want it to actually launch while just testing its existance.

Comment: @ahenderson It isn't a GUI app itself, that's why we rely on an external editor.

Comment: What operating system does this target?

Comment: @Rapptz: RedHat + Kedit = Linux

Comment: I would just try to execute the editor, and if that fails, it obviously isn't in the path! [If you don't want it to show up on the screen, try something like `--version` as an argument].

Comment: Thanks, I guess I failed to read that.

Comment: @CarlNorum: A call to `getenv` and launching a shell process are not quite the same thing reimplemented.

Comment: @steveo225: The *nix way is using the editor that the user configured in either `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` (I'd go for the former). Any other thing is imposing your choice on your user.

Comment: @David I don't know about other distros, but both of these variables are empty by default on my kubuntu 12.10 system. All of that despite the fact that I pretty much only use vim. There has never been a need for me to set either $EDITOR or $VISUAL.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That is what we do, although we have our own environment variable, we only impose a default if that is empty. I just want to make sure the user supplied editor exists or show an error, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: @steveo225: Do you have a specific objection to Mats suggestion? It seems you believe that you cannot figure out if "nothing happens" because the editor just quit with no changes, or if there was no editor. But, that's not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out these functions in the manual

```
char *getenv(const char *name);

int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

or `open` and `fopen`

Comment: I am familiar with them both, however, I was hoping to find an answer that does not require me to parse `$PATH`, loop over each entry, and stat the editor to verify it exists. I was hoping that there was already something that did that.

Comment: I ultimately did just loop through each `$PATH` entry and `stat` the editor to check for existence

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execlp` to start the editor, it searches in the current environment's `PATH`. It also sets `errno` to `ENOENT` ("No such file or directory") on failure so you can catch the non-existent editor condition.

```
char *editor = getenv ("EDITOR");
if(execlp(editor, "foo.txt", (char *) 0))
    perror("Error launching editor");
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are applying `fork()` or `forkpty()` followed by `execlp()` or `execvp()`. Basically, you just need to check if `exec?p()` returns (it only returns if it fails). If so, you just signal to your parent process that the failure occurred. One way to do that is with the `exit()` status. The parent can capture this status by using `wait()` to reap the child process.

```
#define EXEC_FAIL_MAGIC 177
void edit (const char *e) {
    int status = 0;
    pid_t p = fork();
    switch (p) {
    default: /* parent */
        while (wait(&status) != p) {}
        break;
    case 0:  /* child */
        execlp(e, e, "foo.txt", (char *)0);
        exit(EXEC_FAIL_MAGIC);
    case -1: /* error */
        fail("fork() failed");
    }
    if (!WIFEXITED(status)) fail("abnormal termination of editor");
    if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == EXEC_FAIL_MAGIC) fail("execlp failed");
    if (WEXITSTATUS(status) != EXIT_SUCCESS) fail("editor had failure");
}
```